# Sounds working on Lollipop but not on kitkat or older versions

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I made a method I'm using in onCreate, it's called loadSounds, and depending on the version I use the SoundPool Builder or the deprecated version if it's an older version of Android......But sounds only work on Lollipop devices......What could be wrong....the app runs in both versions.....The variable that holds the SoundPool is declared outside of onCreate as an object attribute  private static SoundPool mySounds;

Thanks in advance!!!

```
private void loadSounds(){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN).setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME).build();

            mySounds = new SoundPool.Builder().
                    setMaxStreams(10).
                    setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes).
                    build();

            correctAnswerID = mySounds.load(this, R.raw.correctanswer, 1);
            incorrectAnswerID = mySounds.load(this, R.raw.incorrectanswer, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            mySounds= new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE,1);
            correctAnswerID = mySounds.load(this, R.raw.correctanswer, 1);
            incorrectAnswerID = mySounds.load(this, R.raw.incorrectanswer, 1);

        }

    }
```

The method that uses the sounds is(if the answer is correct plays the correctanswer mp3, otherwise it plays the wronganswer mp3) :

```
if(selectedAnswer.equals(currentAnswer) || isEnharmonic ){

            correctAnswers+=1;
            reproduceAnswerSound("Correct");

        }
        else
        {
            incorrectAnswers+=1;
            reproduceAnswerSound("Incorrect");


        }
```

and the method that reproduce the sounds is like this:

```
private void reproduceAnswerSound(String type){



        if(type.equals("Correct")){

           mySounds.play(correctAnswerID,1,1,1,0,1);


        }else if(type.equals("Incorrect"))
        {
            mySounds.play(incorrectAnswerID,1,1,1,0,1);

        }

    }
```

Comment: BTW, maybe you should change `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` to `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`

Comment: @AntonMalyshev  it's not working my friend. Sounds play only in Lollipop and not in 4.2.2 and 4.4.4....what else could be wrong??

Comment: already solved it......the problem was on the line that declared the soundpool the old way on the else, I replaced that line for this, with the first argument with 1 instead of a 10 and the second argument with stream music instead of the default stream--------------------->

mySounds= new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);